# I'm doing something wrong with the events in this tiny Backbone app

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to understand how events work in Backbone. The following seems to me to be a pretty minimal example, so what am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>events</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.7/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.5.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  window.PasteView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '#paste',

    events : {
      'keyup' : 'callback',
    },

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'callback');
    },

    render: function(){
    },
    callback : function(){
      $('body').append('<p>callback called</p>');
    }
  });

  window.paste = new PasteView;
})

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="paste">
  <p>Every time you hit a key there should be a console.log event</p>
  <textarea id="text" ></textarea>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Shouldn't the `keyup` event be firing the `callback` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's several things that are missing and/or incorrect in this example.

Backbone's declarative events for views require a valid 'el' to be either specified directly (as your trying to do) or generated by the backbone view itself. all events are scoped within the context of the 'el', when the events are bound.

if you specify an el, as you've done here, then the element that you specify must exist within the html of the page at the time that the code is parsed. if you don't specify an el, then backbone will generate one for you.

here's a few examples:

**sample #1**

allow the el to be generated and click a button within it:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click #thatThing": "youClickedIt"
  },

  youClickedIt: function(){
    alert("you clicked it!");
  },

  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html("Click me");
    return this;
  }
});

$(function(){
  var el = new MyView().render().el;
  $("body").append(el);
});
```

and here's the HTML:

```
<html>
  <script src="...thisExample.js"></script>
  <script src="...jQuery.js"></script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

in this example, the "render" method will add a button to the el of the view (which is a div by default). the el (which now contains the button) is then appended to the body of the html. now when you click on the button, you'll see the alert box.

note that if the button does not exist within the el, clicking on it won't cause the alert box to show. the events you declare are always scoped to the el of the view.

**sample #2**

if you want to specify an 'el' to be an element in the page...

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#something",

  events: {
    "click #thatThing": "youClickedIt"
  },

  youClickedIt: function(){
    alert("you clicked it!");
  }
});

$(function(){
  var el = new MyView().render().el;
  $("body").append(el);
});
```

and here's the HTML:

```
<html>
  <script src="...thisExample.js"></script>
  <script src="...jQuery.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="something">
      <button id='thatThing'>Click me</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

in this example, there is no "render" method because the html already exists. instead, we're just attaching the view to the existing "#something" div. the declared event, then, is scoped with the el and it will find the "thatThing" button. so when you click on it, you get the alert box.

note that if the button does not exist within the "something" el, clicking on it won't cause the alert box to show. the events you declare are always scoped to the el of the view.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this fantastic comment Derick.

One observation: I couldn't get the line "var el = new MyView.render().el;" to work -- I had to use two lines: "var view = new MyView; var el = view.render().el;" Any idea what's up with that?

Comment: syntax error from answering things way too late at night :) "var view = new MyView().render().el" should do it... either way, glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have a `body` tag inside your html. Thus, `$('body').append(...)` will not work.

Comment: Duh, thanks. However, the event still doesn't seem to be firing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, shouldn't `PasteView` extend `Backbone.View` and not `Backbone.Model` ?